# How do I run a jquery after 'change' event in .done() ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using PHP Codeigniter, jQuery 2.0.3.

I have a form contains text boxes, and html table. Two of the columns in the html table are casaded dropdown.

The cascaded dropdown, let's say, dropdown A and dropdown B, by default the dropdown A will list out 10 options, it is an item category.
While dropdown B list out nothing. When A is changed, B will populate some option related to the dropdown A (its category), and it's done in

`$(document).on("change","select[name^='ast_group']",function()`

below.

When I choose a value from checkbox and click a button on that page, it will run a JS function that
draw data from MySQL via ajax and put it in my form > input element, 
and also the HTML table. (But the database only have a value of dropdown B, not dropdown A).

The first JS function run is dialog_purchase_request_pull_data(data_purchase_request);
The ajax request inside this function then call JS function insert_detail(result) upon its success.

Inside the insert_detail function, a for loop call another function add_row(tableID,data_ajax);
Inside this add_row function I call ajax to get the value of dropdown A.

I get the value of dropdown A already, but I miss something so that I can't put it directly.
**On this line:**

```
$("#ast_group"+name_cnt).val(obj[0].group_parent_id).change();
```

I have changed the option of dropdown A, and trigger 'change' event so that dropdown B will populate the related options.
This is where I can't find where to put : `$("#ast_sub_group"+name_cnt).val(data_ajax.item_group);` 
So that it will update the dropdown B option after 'change' event has been triggered.

**This is my JS:**

```
<script>
//populate sub group if group changed
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(document).on("change","select[name^='ast_group']",function(){             
        var name_str = $(this).attr('id');
        var name_len = name_str.length;
        var name_cnt = name_str.substring(name_len-1,name_len); 
        $.ajax({
            url:"../asset/ajax_get_sub_group/"+$(this).val(),
            success: function(result){              
                    var detail_result = JSON.parse(result);         
                    $("select[id^='ast_sub_group"+name_cnt+"']").find('option').remove();   
                    $("select[id^='ast_sub_group"+name_cnt+"']").append("<option value='-1'>Select..</option>");
                    for (var i =0; i <detail_result.length;i++){
                        $("select[id^='ast_sub_group"+name_cnt+"']").append("<option value='"+detail_result[i].group_id+"'>"+detail_result[i].group_name+"</option>");
                    }
            }
        });     
    }); 
});
</script>
<script>
function add_row(tableID,data_ajax){
    var name_str = $('#'+tableID+' > tbody > tr:last > td:eq(1) select').attr('id');
    if(typeof(name_str)=="undefined"){
        name_str = "ast_group0";
    }
    var name_len = name_str.length; 
    var name_cnt = parseInt(name_str.substring("ast_group".length,name_len)) +  1;
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    //select init
    var ast_group = '<?php echo sw_CreateSelect('ast_group',$ddl_asset_group,'group_id','group_name',NULL,array('initialvalue'=>'-1','initialdisplay'=>'Select..'));?>';
    var ast_group_buffer = $(ast_group);ast_group_buffer.attr('name','ast_group[]');ast_group_buffer.attr('id','ast_group'+name_cnt);
    var ast_sub_group = '<?php echo sw_CreateSelect('ast_sub_group',$ddl_asset_sub_group,'group_id','group_name',NULL,array('initialvalue'=>'-1','initialdisplay'=>'Select..'));?>';
    var ast_sub_group_buffer = $(ast_sub_group);ast_sub_group_buffer.attr('name','ast_sub_group[]');ast_sub_group_buffer.attr('id','ast_sub_group'+name_cnt);

    var del_link = '<i class="fa fa-ban del_row"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
    var newRow = 
    "<tr height='30px'>"+
        "<td align='center'>"+del_link+"<span>"+rowCount+"</span>"+"</td>"+
        "<td>"+ast_group_buffer.get(0).outerHTML+"</td>"+
        "<td>"+ast_sub_group_buffer.get(0).outerHTML+"</td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' name='ast_name[]' id='ast_name"+name_cnt+"' class='form-control' value='"+data_ajax.item_name+"'></td>"+
        "<td><input type='number' name='ast_qty[]' id='ast_qty"+name_cnt+"' class='form-control' value='"+data_ajax.item_qty+"'></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' name='ast_price[]' id='ast_price"+name_cnt+"' class='form-control' value='"+data_ajax.item_price+"'></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' name='sub_total[]' id='sub_total"+name_cnt+"' class='form-control' value='"+data_ajax.item_total+"'readonly></td>"+
    "</tr>";
    //select option 
    if($('#'+tableID+' > tbody > tr').length == 0){
        $('#'+tableID+' > tbody ').append(newRow);
    }else{
        $('#'+tableID+' > tbody > tr:last').after(newRow);
    }
    var ajax_result = [];
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('asset/ajax_get_parent_group');?>",
        data: {ajax_group_id:data_ajax.item_group}, 
        dataType: "json"/*,
        success: function(result){          
            //return result;
            //alert(result[0].group_parent_id);
            //$("#ast_group"+name_cnt).val(result[0].group_parent_id).change(); 
        }*/
    }).done(function (obj){
        alert('group change');
        $("#ast_group"+name_cnt).val(obj[0].group_parent_id).change();
        $("#ast_sub_group"+name_cnt).val(data_ajax.item_group);
    /*}).done(function (obj){
        alert('wait group change for sub group');
        $("#ast_sub_group"+name_cnt).val(data_ajax.item_group);*/
    }); 
}

function dialog_purchase_request_pull_data(data_purchase_request){
    $("#doc_ref").val(data_purchase_request['doc_num']);
    $("#request_for").val(data_purchase_request['request_for']);
    $("#request_dept").val(data_purchase_request['request_dept']);
    $("#doc_note").val(data_purchase_request['doc_note']);
    var doc_id = data_purchase_request['doc_id'];
    var data_ajax_raw = $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url('purchase/ajax_purchase_request');?>",
        data: {purreq:doc_id},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result){              
            insert_detail(result);          
        }
    });     
}
function insert_detail(data){
    var tbl = document.getElementById("table_detail");
    var tbl_lastrow = tbl.rows.length -1;
    document.getElementById("table_detail").deleteRow(tbl_lastrow); //delete last row
    var data_ajax = Object();   
    for (var datum in data){
        data_ajax.item_name = data[datum].item_name;
        data_ajax.item_qty = data[datum].item_qty;
        data_ajax.item_price = data[datum].item_price;
        data_ajax.item_total = data[datum].item_total;
        data_ajax.item_group = data[datum].item_group;
        add_row('table_detail',data_ajax);
    }


    /*$("#ast_group1").val(1).change();
    $("#ast_sub_group1").val(24);

    $("#ast_group2").val(4).change();   
    $("#ast_sub_group2").val(101);*/
    addRow("table_detail"); //add empty row
}
</script>
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.
JMS

Comment: TL;DR, me thinks you should probably try and minimize this to whatever the issue actually is ?

Comment: What is the purpose of `dialog_purchase_request_pull_data`? It never gets called in the provided code. Also, `add_row` does an Ajax call for every added row.. just out of curiosity, how many initial requests to you have with this code?

Comment: Yeah I didn't put the code that call dialog_purchase_request_pull_data, because it is running already. I just need to find the way how to choose the dropdown B, using jQuery, and executed after: $("#ast_group"+name_cnt).val(obj[0].group_parent_id).change(); in .done() method is finished executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has does not directly address the question, but I believe it has more value as an answer than as a simple comment.

Your setup seems overly complicated and not optimal. You can greatly reduce complexity by using reusable components, such as [select2](https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for your lists and, perhaps, implementing the Ajax search functionality or setting list's B data on list A change.

For Ajax search, just disable the list B until something is selected in list A, and configure list B with the proper Ajax settings (i.e. URL arguments) with the selected value from list A.

Or you can simply set list B's values from list A change event.

What you are trying to do is something that has been done many times before, but I think your approach might not be the best way for this.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and recommendation.. :), i'm now trying to restructuring the way i code to be more simple.. also, those select2 is nice.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

did you try .done() method?

```
$.ajax({
url: "test.html",
context: document.body
}).done(function() {
$( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Comment: Yes I did. the issue here is i miss something that make me unable to change the dropdown B after dropdown A is changed in .done() function.

Comment: because in .done() function, dropdown A is already set to a specific value based on ajax call, and trigger .change() event. And now I have to put the data_ajax.item_group to dropdown B, whose options are populated on dropdown A's change event.